# best_score_ parameter from GridSearchCV from spark-sklearn doesn't work with version 0.2.3

Tags: apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark, grid-search

I am looking to use best_score_ parameter from GridSearchCV function, but it looks like that is not present in the latest version of the library spark-sklearn (version 0.2.3). When I'm trying to uninstall the latest version and reinstall and older version (with version 0.2.0) with the command 
pip install spark-sklearn-0.2.0
It does not work. How can I install older versions of spark-sklearn library in my cluster environments? best_score_ parameter seems to work fine in version 0.2.0.
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn/issues/80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known issue with spark-sklearn version 0.2.3 for not having best_score_ parameter in gridSearchCV. The issue can be found here at
https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn/issues/73

To install older version of the library, use the following command:
pip install spark-sklearn==0.2.0